# How to declare array of class types in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a java code like below.

```
myclass a1 = new myclass(p1,p2);
myclass a2 = new myclass(p3,p4);
```

I want to do something like

```
myclass a[1] = new myclass(p1,p2);
myclass a[2] = new myclass(p3,p4);
```

how to do it ?

Comment: In c#? You are interested in having an array of custom objects, yes?

Comment: `myclass[] a = new myclass[2];` and then `a[0] = new myclass(p1, p2); a[1] = new myclass(p3, p4);`.

Comment: just edited. The code is in Java 
@Kayaman will that work in Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myclass[] myArray = new myclass[5];

myArray[0] = new myclass(p1,p3)
```

This is valid in java.

Comment: i think it should be myclass[] myArray = new myclass[5]; ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myclass[] a = new myclass[]{
    new myclass(p1,p2),
    new myclass(p1,p2)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

it could be done in  one line:

```
myclass[] myArray = myclass[]{ new myclass(p1, p2), new myclass(p3, p4) };
```

This is the same as:

```
myclass[] myArray = new myclass[2];
myArray[0] = new myclass(p1, p2);
myArray[1] = new myclass(p3, p4);
```